# Should I also index columns included in a PRIMARY KEY?

Tags: mysql, database-design, indexing, primary-key

This question suddenly popped into my head...  I have a table that ties two other tables together based on their ID.  The `CREATE TABLE` looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `ticket_contact` (
        `ticket_id` INT NOT NULL,
        `entity_id` INT NOT NULL,
        `notify` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        PRIMARY KEY (`ticket_id`, `entity_id`),
        KEY `ticket_id` (`ticket_id`),
        KEY `entity_id` (`entity_id`)
      )
```

I'm wondering if there is any need to include those last two `KEY` lines.  Will it give me improved speed with the following queries, or will individual columns within a `PRIMARY KEY` automatically be indexed?

```
SELECT * FROM ticket_contact WHERE ticket_id=1;
SELECT * FROM ticket_contact WHERE entity_id=1;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An index created by `PRIMARY KEY` is the same as any other (potentially composite) `UNIQUE` index. So you needn't create a separate index for `ticket_id` as it is included as the major column in the `(ticket_id, entity_id)` index.

You would want to create a separate index over `entity_id` if you were commonly doing queries using that column independently of the `ticket_id`.

Answer (score 4):

Think of a PK and an Index as simply a way of forcing your records into sorted order. Databases can search through sorted data much much faster than unsorted data (log n vs linear time).

A composite primary key sorts in the order of columns given, so PK (ticket_id, entity_id) sorts `ticket_id ASC, entity_id ASC`. Since your PK already sorts ticket_ids, it covers the index on `ticket_id`.

However, sorting by `entity_id ASC` with no other columns results in a different sort order. If you needed to query on `entity_id` often, MySQL will perform an index scan (searching through each ticket_id, then binary_searching the results for the matching entity_id). Your separate index on `entity_id` will make queries for entity_id much faster.